# A Pairing Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, pattern

Show how the following words may be sorted into five pairs

> Cameras
> Came
> Apart
> Easy
> Back
> Up
> Broken
> Pieces
> Flights
> Feet

Can you suggest another pair of words which could belong to this group?

Comment: The red herrings are delicious.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are all

> movie titles

The pairings are

> [Five Easy Pieces](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065724/), [5 Flights Up](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2933544/), [5 Broken Cameras](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2125423/), [Five Came Back](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031314/), [Five Feet Apart](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6472976/)

Comment: You're kidding me - this question is open for hours without any interaction, and then TWO of you post within a minute, and with a full set of links too?! That is some cosmic coincidence...!

Comment: Good show, and in front of my response. Nice!

Comment: Nicely done, can you suggest another pair that fits into the group?

Answer (score 15):

The five pairs are all

> films which begin with the number five.

These show the relationships

> [5 Broken Cameras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Broken_Cameras) - 2011 documentary co-directed by Emad Burnat and Guy Davidi.
>  [5 Flights Up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Flights_Up) - 2014 comedy-drama starring Morgan Freeman and Diane Keaton.
>  [Five Came Back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Came_Back) - 1939 melodrama with Chester Morris and Lucille Ball.
>  [Five Easy Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Easy_Pieces) - 1970 drama starring Jack Nicholson.
>  [Five Feet Apart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Feet_Apart) -  2019 American romantic drama starring Haley Lu Richardson and Cole Sprouse.

Another one in this group

> 5 Card Stud -  a 1968 Western with Dean Martin and Robert Mitchum.